# Wie funktioniert "mit" im Satz: Das würde Ärger mit ihm geben

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Vermutlich bedeuten die zwei Sätze nicht das Gleiche:

1. Das würde Ärger mit ihm geben.
2. Das würde ihm Ärger geben.

Es scheint auch, dass "mit … geben" im ersten Satz kein trennbares Verb ist. Eigentlich habe ich die Kombination "mit … geben" im Wörterbuch nicht gefunden.

Deswegen frage ich: Wie funktioniert "mit" in der Bedeutung des ersten Satzes?

Comment: Mitgeben gibt es aber. Lass Dir ein paar gute Ratschläge mitgeben :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das *mit* täuscht, der Unterschied besteht in zwei Formen von *geben*.

Das *geben* im ersten Satz funktioniert ohne Objekt, in der unpersönlichen Konstruktion *es gibt*, also "there is".  *Mit ihm* modifiziert das nur: "there's trouble with him".  *Das* ersetzt hierbei *es* und referenziert auf eine spezifische Situatio,n die im Kontext als bekannt vorausgesetzt wird (also zB. das vorher Genannte).

Im zweiten Satz (der grammatisch, aber nicht ganz akzeptabel formuliert ist) funktioniert *geben* als normales transitives Verb mit zwei Objekten, in der Bedeutung "give":

> *Das gibt [**jemandem (Dat.)**] [**etwas (Akk.)**]*.

Also in etwa, "that would give him trouble".  Der Ausdruck mit *geben* klingt allerdings sehr komisch; normalerweise würde man eher sowas wie *das wird ihm Ärger machen*, *bereiten*, oder *einhandeln* sagen.

---

There is also a separable compound verb *mitgeben*, which does however not occur in either sentence.  You use it like in the following example:

> *Er gibt ihr Kuchen mit*.  "He gives her some cake to take with her."

Comment: Der zweite Satz ist meines Erachtens falsch; _jemandem etwas geben_ kann vorkommen in Phrasen wie _der Erfolg gab ihm mehr Selbstvertrauen, diese Worte gaben ihm neuen Lebensmut_ usw., außerdem in vielen weiteren mehr oder weniger festen Verbindungen: _jm den letzten Anstoß geben zu, jm recht geben, jm mehr Zeit geben (zu), jm (k)eine Chance geben, jm den Rest geben (demoralisieren; töten)_, Für die im 2. Satz gemeinte Bedeutung würde ich auf Deutsch sagen: _Damit wird er sich Ärger einhandeln._

Comment: Eh, da stimme ich dir zu. Deswegen die Relativierung gegen Ende.